# Django filter qs contains filename not working with underscores

Tags: django

my goal is to filter if the name of an uploaded document contains a `search` *(a simple string from an input field submitted by the user)*.
Strangely this works for long substring but not for short ones.

### Example

My filter query is the following:

```
Tab.objects.filter(document__file__icontains=search)
```

where `Tab` is in simplest form a Model class like:

```
class Tab(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

and `Document` is another Model class wit a relation to Tabs and a file field.

```
class Document(models.Model):
    tab = models.ForeignKey(Tab, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=custom_location)
```

### Weird behavior

I've uploaded a file called `example_test_123.pdf` and if my `search` = `example_test` or `test_123.pdf` it results in a hit like expected.

**However, if `search` = `test` the filter doesn't find the file.**

Is this behaviour known or am I missing something here? Is it possible that the built-in name `file` is doing some trouble?

## Edit

1. I changed `file` to `document_file` without success
2. Even `_test` or `test_` is working

## Edit #2

@ Iain Shelvington (Comment)

This is no special function... only setting the subdirs the file should be saved

```
from django.utils.text import slugify

def custom_location(instance, filename):
    return os.path.join('documents', slugify(instance.tab.name), filename)
```

**But your question is pointing me in the right direction for a workaround (thanks):**

I'm doing an annotation before filtering. `companies` is in this case a ManyToManyField to another model:

`tabs = Tab.objects.all().annotate(num_companies=Count('companies'))`

and then filtering for some stuff like

`tabs = tabs.filter(num_companies__gte=3)`

Removing these lines results in a correct filtering.
So I'm doing the annotations after filtering for the filename.

But I'm still curious what's happening here...

Thanks.

(Django 3.2.9 and Python 3.6.8)

Comment: Can you give more details about how the filter is being triggered (with some code), the result you are getting and the `custom_location` function? I'm unable to replicate your issue locally when not using a custom `upload_to` function

Comment: I've edited the Question. Thanks for pointing me to the right direction. Still clueless whats going on here but for now happy with the workaround...